# Assigning the whole array values to another variable in c#?

Tags: c#

I have an array and i want to assign it to another array variable. Here is the code

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            arr1[i] = Convert.ToByte(Tag_uid.Substring(2 * i, 2), 16);
        }



        //Create an array to hold the Command Packet
        byte[] CommandPacket = new byte[9];


        CommandPacket[0] = arr1;   //ERROR: cannot convert type byte[] to byte
```

How can i assign the whole array values to `commandpacket[0]`?

Comment: No you can't. `cannot convert type byte[] to byte` (I also don't think that your loop forming arr1 is correct)

Comment: `CommandPacket[0]`is a single byte. How do you want to assign an array of bytes to it? And if you want CommandPacket (the array) to contain the values of arr1, why don't you simply skip arr1 and assign the values in your loop? And finally: Is it C# or Java? You might want to use correct tags?

Comment: @L.B , I know i can't convert like that, so i needed a way to store the values. the looping of arr1 is correct, it is converting a bunch of strings to byte and stores in an array.

Comment: @igrimpe that was the question i was asking. it is not possible for 'CommandPacket[0]' to hold the data or arr1. btw, skipping arr1 and assigning the values worked.. Thanks Alot. for the tags, if i m not wrong i used c# tag only.. sorry if there was a java tag, i didnt see it.

Comment: @Liban `the looping of arr1 is correct`.  **a)** when `i` exceeds length/2 you will get exception **b)** you take two chars from string(as substring) but incerement `i` by `1`

Comment: @L.B the 'lenght' is defined as 5, so as long as 'i' is less than 5 i guess there is no exception.. for your second point: i have 10 chars, so i am taking each 2 and converting it to byte..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    arr1[i] = Convert.ToByte(Tag_uid.Substring(2 * i, 2), 16);
}

byte[][] CommandPacket = new byte[9][];

CommandPacket[0] = arr1;
```

Comment: Thanks that worked too.. but i guess it is easier to assign 'CommandPacket[]' inside the loop (as @igrimpe suggested above) without going for jagged arrays. anywayz thanks for the help..